# What syntax and parameter placement allows me to specify the radius of this circle inside tikz-pgf?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \path node [draw, circle, inner sep = 0] at (current page.center) {Test circle\ldots};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I have this circle and want to specify it's radius with command I have saved with the name `\sRadius` but I can't find where to place my value for `/tikz/radius`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `minimum width` as you are defining circle as a node shape:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newlength\sRadius
\setlength\sRadius{15cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \path node [draw, circle,minimum width=\sRadius, inner sep =0cm] at (current page.center) {Test circle\ldots};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that the `minimum width` will be equal to the diameter. If you are re-using this node many times, then you may put the parameters inside a tikz style.

Comment: `\tikzset{Circle/.style={shape=circle, minimum size=#1, inner sep=0pt}, Circle/.default=\sRadius}` might be a helpful style.

Comment: But why is the property radius not accessible?

Comment: @Supernovah Because it's a node and many factors effect the radius. The text content, line width, inner sep, outer sep etc. all is considered by TikZ before coming up with a number in the bowels of shape declaration and that is not a fixed number. If you put more text in the node TikZ enlarges the circle. If you need a simple circle use a circle instead of a node.

Comment: Okay so my goal is to draw a number of circles that need to be as wide as the page and slightly smaller and then also a large number of arcs inside them. Is tikz the best library for this?

Comment: @Supernovah `tikz` can do it quite neatly. Use `minimum width = \textwidth` (or `\paperwidth` if you mean it). For arc, you may use something like `\draw (0,0) arc (0:270:5cm);` meaning an arc starting at point (0,0) from angle 0 to 270 with a radius of 5cm. Refer `pgfmanual` for more details (www.texdoc.net).

Comment: I've been trying to make sense of pgfmanual.pdf for a while. It does not help except to describe things which seem can't be done.